# Can Solr run without Lucene?

Tags: oracle, apache, search, solr, lucene

I have an application for Solr that would work great--I'm using it to query an Oracle database and having success with what I'm seeing.

However, the way I have it set up today, it imports the data from Oracle into a local database (I gather this is called Lucene) at which point it shows up as a document in the index.

I'm wondering if there's a way to store this data directly inside Oracle instead of needing to pull it locally. I'm okay taking a performance hit for it to do so. (the data contains personally identifiable information, and I am (rightly) restricted on where I can store that.) Can I leave the data in its original format and have Solr query the database as I would? Can I have the Lucene index live inside Oracle somewhere?

Does anyone know if this is doable, or does Solr 100% require Lucene as a backend?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704644/difference-between-solr-and-lucene

Comment: I did see that link, and it seems to imply that Solr is dependent on Lucene, but I wondered if anyone had run an alternate configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**does Solr 100% require Lucene as a backend?**

Yes. Solr can't function without Lucene. It might be a standalone application but it uses Lucene at it's core.

As to whether or not you can store the index in a database, this seems to suggest you can : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17371651/2039359 (which in turn points to [Create Lucene Index in database using JdbcDirectory](http://mprabhat.com/2012/08/13/create-lucene-index-in-database-using-jdbcdirectory/))by extending [Compass](http://www.compass-project.org/) but that seems to be defunct (http://thedudeabides.com/articles/the_future_of_compass/) so whether or not you should is a different question